# I have restricted background data but i am still getting whatsapp and facebook messages,,, am using an android 8.1 oreo

Tags: notifications, settings

I have restricted background data but i am still getting Whatsapp and Facebook messages notifications.

I'm using an android 8.1 Oreo.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Push messages are usually not received by the app itself, but by the Google Push Notification Service (part of the "Google [Play] Services"). This prevents that every app have to built their own notification system which would cost a lot of battery and traffic.

Comment: To elaborate on this a little, in general you cannot disable background data for Google Services... Background data on or off is not relevant, this is considered an essential service and always has access to data when it is available. Most apps such as Facebook Messenger, Whatsapp, and most messaging apps, even many Echange email compatible apps, use the Google Push Notification service. To my knowledge this cannot be disabled without Airplane mode, or root access using 3rd party tools as disabling causes lots of other things to not function correctly.

Comment: @acejavelin While I haven't tested whether or not it works, I can "flip the switch" on Google Services' access to mobile data on my phone. I have a Honor, so it's probably a feature of EMUI.